# Rails Form is not accepting tab key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `text_field` in `form_tag` which can accept any type of keys. And I need html of that text_field I gave tabs, but its not converting it to `&emsp;` other than this everything is getting converted to proper html but tabs are coming as blank space. Is rails restrict something while submitting form?

Comment: Post some code. It's unclear what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: It may be an issue with encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your `text_field` with `<pre>` tags.

```
<pre>
  <%= text_field ... %>
</pre>
```

Comment: Quick google yielded that suggestion. I haven't used it before, but someone had success with it. It looks surprising to me too. I didn't think `<pre>` effected anything in an input box.

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub to replace tabs with `&emsp;` after form submission.

```
text.gsub!(/\t/,'&emsp;')
```